# Getting Illegal State Exception in Regex

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

I am trying to remove a specific lines in a text file using regex but I am receiving an Illegal State Exception. I am recently trying to get accustomed to regex and have tried to to use match.matches(); but that solution has not worked for me . any advice to what I am doing wrong

```java
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TestFile.txt"));
    //System.out.println(br.toString());

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line= br.readLine() ;

    while (br.readLine() != null ) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        //System.out.println("test1"); { 
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"]+|\"[^\"]*\"");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
        String match = regexMatcher.group();// here is where the illegalstateexception occurs
        match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
        match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
        list.add(match);    
    //  }

    //      br.close();
    System.out.println(br);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
>   at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
>   at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)

Comment: There is no match result. Before using the ```group``` method, you should call the ```find``` method to check for the result. What is the content of the ```TestFile.txt``` file?

Comment: I am new to regex what would be the purpose of the find method if I am using Matcher?.The contents of the text file is unwanted metadata </metadata>2019-05-10T06:00:00+00:00 pspapi-ctwbcp4a #Version: 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Use `Matcher.find()` method to see if there is a match in the regular expression pattern. Debug the results of the `regexMatcher.find()` method in the IDE(e.g. IntelliJ)

```java
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TestFile.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String line;

    // Assign one line read from the file to a variable
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"]+|\"[^\"]*\"");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);

        // Returns true if a match is found for the regular expression pattern.
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            String match = regexMatcher.group();
            match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
            match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
            list.add(match);
        }
    }

    // What is the purpose of this code?
    System.out.println(br);

    // If you want to output the string elements of the list
    System.out.println(list.toString());

    // must be closed after use.(to prevent memory leak)
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // exception handling
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the while loop wrong so it causes the line to be null, try that:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TestFile.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;     // <--- FIXED

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--- FIXED
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"]+|\"[^\"]*\"");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
        String match = regexMatcher.group();// here is where the illegalstateexception occurs
        match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
        match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
        list.add(match);    
    }

    br.close();

    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```